# Derivative of "asymmetric" Dirac delta function

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

Define a function:

\begin{align}
  M\left({m}\right): \mathbb{R} &\to \mathbb{C} \\
  t &\mapsto \lim_{k \to \infty} \sum_{s \in \{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\}}m(s) k e^{k(s - t)}.
  \label{eqn:pointmass}
\end{align}

$m$  is a function from times t to values, and $M$ maps $m$ to another function from times $t$ to values.

I hope that this definition of $M$ makes it so that for any $t_1 < t_2$,
\begin{align}
  \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left[M(m)\right](t) \,dt = \sum_{t \in \{t : m(t) \ne 0, t_1 \le t < t_2\}}m(t).
\end{align}

Sometimes, I end up doing some manipulations, and I end up with
\begin{align}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{dM(m)}{dt} \cdot x\,dt
\end{align}
where $x$ is also a function of $t$.

Am I supposed to replace this with $-\sum_{s \in \{s : m(s) \ne 0, t_1 \le s < t_2\}}\frac{dx}{dt} m(s)$?  Or zero?

Comment: What is $m$ ?  What do you mean by "functor"?  It seems you do not mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor

Comment: @GEdgar You're right, I was confused.  I think I was thinking of functional, but I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try an example.  Correct me if I am making a wrong interpretation.

Say we have $m$ defined as $m(1) = 2, m(3) = 7$ and $m(s) = 0$ for all other $s$.  Then

For $t<1$ we have $\{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\}$ is empty, so $M(m)(t) = 0$.

For $t=1$ we have $\{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\} = \{1\}$, so
$$
M(m)(1) = \lim_{k\to\infty} 2 k e^{k 0} = \infty
$$
For $1 < t < 3$ we have $\{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\} = \{1\}$, so
$$
M(m)(1) = \lim_{k\to\infty} 2 k e^{k (1-t)} = 0
$$
For $t = 3$ we have $\{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\} = \{1,3\}$, so
$$
M(m)(3) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \big(2 k e^{k (1-3)} + 7 k e^{k 0}\big) = \infty
$$
For $t > 3$ we have $\{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\} = \{1,3\}$, so
$$
M(m)(t) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \big(2 k e^{k (1-t)} + 7 k e^{k (3-t)}\big) = 0
$$

As written, then, we have all integrals
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\left[M(m)\right](t) \,dt = 0
$$
since the integrand is zero almost everywhere.  So what you wrote is not what you want.

It seems, perhaps, you want the limit outside the integral:
$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_{t_1}^{t_2}\sum_{s \in \{s : m(s) \ne 0, s \le t\}}m(s) k e^{k(s - t)}\;dt =
\sum_{t \in \{t : m(t) \ne 0, t_1 \le t < t_2\}}m(t)
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I don't understand why your argument doesn't apply to the Dirac delta function just the same way.  For convenience, I want a mathematical function whose finite integral is a finite sum over nonzero values of $m$.  Also, my question here is given such an object, what amI supposed to do with its derivative?

Comment: The "Dirac delta function" is not a function, it is a "Schwartz distribution" or "generalized function".  To ask questions about it in a math forum, you will need to use proper definitions and terminology.

Comment: I put it into the title, declared a similar motivation, and gave what I thought was a similar definition.  If you would be so kind as to help me use more proper terminology, that would be really appreciated.  Also, why doesn't your argument apply to Dirac's delta function?

Comment: My argument does apply to the Dirac delta function.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions for valid ways to deal with the Dirac delta function.

Comment: Yes, I flipped through that, but to be honest, I'm less interested in the finer details.  I'm really interested in my main question, which is: “suppose that there is a Dirac-like function $M$ whose bounded integral works like a sum over a half-open interval of times, then what is the bounded integral of $\frac{dM}{dt} x_t$?